# Find joints positions in 3D robotic manipulator?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, 3d, transformation, kinematics

I have been trying to solve this 3D mechanics problem, but can't seem to be able to figure out what the best way to do it is.
I have this $3D$ robot manipulator with $3$ rotary joints $(B, C, D)$. I would like to work out the $3D$ position coordinates of the joints $B, C$ and $D$ relative to the end effector $A$ (of known position $0,0,0$ and given orientation). The orientations and lengths of the links $L1, L2$ and $L3$ are known.
[image]

What would be the easiest way to solve this? Is it necessary to use transformation matrices or is there an easier way to do it using $3D$ geometry? Thank you for your time!

Comment: You would have to define two relative coordinates $ \theta_R, \phi_R$ for Rotor B and C, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you please explain this in a bit more detail? I am not entirely sure what you mean by relative coordinates and how I would go ahead with that

Comment: Sit at the rotor B in terms of spherical coordinate. Since the radial distances are fixed. Out of the 3 coordinates in spherical system how many would you need to require to specify the next rotor?

Comment: This is a standard [kinematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_kinematics) question  dealt with in robotics books. See for example [this online course](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/index.php/Modern_Robotics_Videos#Chapter_4:_Forward_Kinematics).

Comment: @Max So it's a standard forward kinematics problem that requires transformation matrices to solve?

Comment: I'd say the transformation matrices is the easiest way, but I'm not really a specialist (and besides, what is easiest is subjective).

Comment: When you write that orientation of the segments is known, you should be clear in what frame of reference and what coordinate format that is known. If you had absolute 3d unit vectors pointing that direction, it would be really easy, while local rotation angles are harder. In that case I'd go with matrices because it's easy to think about the problem in that setup. Likely would be using homogeneous coordinates and $4\times4$ matrices, so that you can express rotation and translation using the same framework.

Comment: Hi @MvG, thank you for your kind reply! They are absolute 3D unit vectors and the orientation is expressed in terms of Euler angles. How would that help solve the problem?